Crocodile paradox
About the Crocodile The Paradox Conditions
A crocodile kidnaps a child and gives the father a condition: “I will return the child to you if and only if you correctly guess whether I will return the child or not.” The crocodile then decides whether to return the child or not.
Foreword
I spent about 15 minutes thinking about this paradox and came to the obvious conclusion that the problem is incorrectly formulated. If there are any mistakes in my reasoning, I would like to know, thank you.
Reasoning
Logical Analysis

The father says P: “You will return my child.”
2.The crocodile says Q: “I will return the child.”
The father says X: not P (¬P)
The crocodile says Y: not Q (¬Q)

Analysis

If P and Q, the crocodile returns the child.
If ¬P and Q, the crocodile does not return the child.
If P and ¬Q, the crocodile does not return the child.
If ¬P and ¬Q, the crocodile returns the child.

Reasoning
The paradox only arises in case 4, where the father says, “You will not return the child,” but the crocodile responds, “I intended not to return the child, and since you guessed correctly, I will return the child.” Thus, the crocodile, having intended not to return the child, still ends up returning the child. Clearly, the crocodile trapped itself with these conditions, as the fourth scenario forces it to return the child. But is this truly a paradox? It may seem contradictory, but I don’t believe it is if interpreted in the following way:
“I will return the child only if and only if our answers coincide.” “You will return the child” and “I will return the child” coincide, so the crocodile returns the child. “You will not return the child” and “I will not return the child” also coincide, so the crocodile returns the child. Therefore, it can be formulated as follows:
The father gets the child back if and only if the father’s and the crocodile’s answers are either both true or both false. Hence, there is no longer a paradox.

If you reformulate a paradox to make it no longer a paradox, then it's no longer a paradox. You changed "guess whether I will return the child" to "guess whether I'll say I will return the child", and then you allow them to simply not do the thing they said they'd do. That's an entirely different hypothetical.

The crocodile dilemma is formulated the way it is formulated, what does it mean exactly to say that it is formulated "incorrectly"? That one can formulate a non-paradox instead of a paradox is not particularly interesting.

What is the question here? Also why is 4. the only paradoxical case but not 2.? Like in 2 he says that he WILL return the child, but ends up not actually doing it, so he WON'T return the child, right?

Perhaps this shows that classical logic does not model time.

If the crocodile eats your kid, you'd be justified in keeping him in a box, putting him on display in a circus, and making him talk for everybody.

To speak of the crocodile's intentions only muddies the waters since presumably the crocodile could intend one action and change its mind.
One way to think about what is going on here is to think of it as a game. The father makes a move by predicting what the crocodile will do and then the crocodile makes a move by returning the child or not. If the father predicts that the crocodile will return the child then the crocodile is free to make either move. But if the father predicts the crocodile will not return the child then the crocodile has no legal move.
Depending on why the game is happening, this might be a paradox or it might not. In games like chess and checkers, it is not paradoxical if a player has no legal move. If that situation arises it just means the game has come to an end. That is itself part of the rules of those games. In the crocodile game, the rules don't tell us what happens if the crocodile has no legal move. The game is defective if it doesn't tell us what happens in that circumstance.
If you like thinking about puzzles like this, I suggest the following one. It is not a paradox, but it has the merit that you can take the role of Alice and try it out on your friends.
Alice and Bob are sitting at a table. Each has a piece of paper, a pen and a cup. Alice says, "I will write a prediction on my piece of paper and place it under my cup. If you can correctly guess whether my prediction comes true, I'll give you some money. To make your guess, you need to write either the word YES or the word NO on your piece of paper and place it under your cup. If you write anything else, or if you write both, the offer is void." Alice writes her prediction and places it under her cup where Bob cannot see it. Bob now writes YES or NO on his piece of paper and places it under his cup. Now comes the reveal. Someone lifts Alice's cup and reads her prediction. It says: Bob will place under his cup a piece of paper on which he has written the word NO. Sadly for Bob, he cannot win the money. And this explains why Alice has no friends.

Your last paragraph reminds be of a common scam. A person approach’s an obviously pregnant woman and offers to be that they can predict the sex of the child. The woman pays $10 which the predicter will keep if they are right but if they are wrong, the woman comes back and gets $20. They then make a verbal prediction and writes the prediction and puts it into an envelope which is then sealed. They can make an honest buck because they have a slightly better than 50-50 chance if they predict boy (because more boys are born than girls), and …

… even if they a wrong, a significant number of people won’t come back. But here’s the scam, what they write is the opposite of what they said, when the person comes back several months later, they can be convinced that they misremembered what was said because, look, there it is in black and white.

This isn't a paradox. If the father says he'll return the kid and the croc does, no problem.
If the father predicts that the beast will return the child, and the crocodile doesn't, Then the father was wrong and the croc eats the kid. That's not a contradiction either.
If the father predicts the croc will eat the kid, then  no matter what the monster does, it was lying about what it was going to do.
In any case, there's no paradox.

I predict the crocodile will be eaten in return. All that preys on mankind has terminal stupidity.

Ironically, so does mankind.

@Miss_Understands technically, since man does prey on man (rarely in a literal "eat them" sense, but very commonly otherwise) that's already included!

Actually without further explanation only 2 cases are well defined:

Father: You will return the child
Crocodile: Returns the child


and Father: You will return the child
Crocodile: Crocodile keeps the child.

So if the father says "You will return the child", he's at the mercy of what the crocodile wants to do, because what ever the crocodile actually does is covered by the conditions.
The problem arises if the father says: "You will not return the child". Because now every possible outcome is in contradiction with the conditions.
If the crocodile keeps the child the father is right and due to the condition the crocodile ought to return the child, but at the same time the father said that the child is not returned so returning it would be in contradiction with the condition as well.
While if the crocodile returns the child that is not what the father said, so he'd ought to keep it, but keeping it would again be what the father said so not returning the child would also be in contradiction with the condition.
So the father has the choice between being at the mercy of the crocodile ("will return") and stalling any decision by forcing the crocodile into a paradoxical state ("will not return").
(So in other words the father would also be at the mercy of the crocodile who made the rules and thus is likely also able to break them. (Though that's thinking outside of the box, so not sure people are going to like that)).

The problem is phrased as a statement of intent i.e. before the event has taken place - it may prove true or false. If the statement is view  aposteriori i.e. after the event and the statement is asserted as true then it simplifies to the statement that the child was returned. In either case there is no paradox.

There are two conditional requirements for the crocodile to eat the child:

Any promises and agreements the crocodile chooses to follow.
Control over the child that the crocodile only initially possesses.

If the father says to the crocodile, it will return the child; the crocodile can do the opposite while retaining control. The crocodile is now free to eat the child, and everything is consistent.
But if the father does not believe the crocodile will return the child, the crocodile is forced to do precisely this. And that action cannot be done while retaining the control. After that, the crocodile is free to eat the child but no longer has control over the victim.
